# Do I have to make a local version of my website before I can use Xdebug?

Tags: debug

I am trying to find out a way to debug my website. This is a very new field for me, so I am following the "Using an IDE" steps on this page: https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_debug_your_code and some other related pages(For configuring eclipse, xdebug, etc..).

As the page suggests, xdebug is a prevailing tool for debugging. I have never heard it before, the only thing I know about it now is that it is an extension of PHP which help debug. I noticed that in my XAMPP installation, xdebug is installed(at least there is a xdebug section in php.ini), however, in my webspace, there is no xdebug section in php.ini. So my questions are:

1) Being there no xdebug section in php.ini of my webspace, does this mean my webserver doesn't support xdebug? If yes, is there any web hosting company that has xdebug available, or at least offer this possibility?

2) Regardless of xdebug, is it possible to debug a joomla site in a remote server? Is it a common practice to clone the site to local before debugging it?

3) My xampp control panel version is 3.2.1. About xdebug configuration in XAMPP, on this page https://docs.joomla.org/Edit_PHP.INI_File_for_XDebug it says "For Windows, it should look like the example below:

```
[XDebug]
;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
zend_extension_ts="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=10000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

However, the xdebug section in my php.ini looks like this

```
[XDebug]
;zend_extension = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
;xdebug.remote_enable = 0
;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "D:\xampp\tmp"
```

How should I edit it in order to enable xdebug?

Comment: I think this question should be asked on Stack Overflow rather than here, as it's not really related to Joomla itself, but related to your dev environment